# Chrome extension, how to exclude chrome:// URIs in manifest.json

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to prevent users from running my extension on `chrome://` pages. When they click my extension, they will get an error which shows up next to my extension and is really annoying:

[image: picture of error]

## What I have tried

Here is my `manifest.json`. I would like to completely ignore `chrome://` URIs.

```js
    "content_scripts": [
        {
            "matches": ["http://*/*", "https://*/*"],
            "exclude_globs": ["chrome://*"],
            "css": ["style.css"]
        }
    ],
    "background": {
        "persistent": false,
        "scripts": ["background.js"],
        "css": ["style.css"]
    }
```

Here is my `background.js`:

```js
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {file: "a.js"}, function(){
        chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {file: "b.js"});
    });
});
```

I would really just like to match all `http` and `https` urls, and ignore everything else, which is what I thought  `"matches": ["http://*/*", "https://*/*"],` would do here, but it's not working for some reason.

I've tried using exclude matches, but the result is the same. I've tried using `"*://*/*"` as the matches pattern but that also doesn't work, even though the [match patterns docs](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/match_patterns) say that using `*` for the scheme should match only with `http/https`. So I'm out of ideas.

Alternately, if it's possible to catch this error to prevent it from showing up, that would also work for me.

Comment: Your declared content scripts don't need that as they already are limited to http and https. The problem is caused by something else, most probably chrome.tabs.executeScript.

Comment: How can I avoid this problem? I'll add my background script too.

Comment: The usual measure are 1) debugging in devtools by setting breakpoints and then inspecting what's happening, this is the most important step, 2) checking `tab.url` before doing anything, 3) simply suppressing the error by adding `chrome.runtime.lastError;` dummy access in the API callbacks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to prevent this error by checking the tab url inside the event listener in my `background.js` file:

```js
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
    if(!tab.url || !tab.url.startsWith('http')){
        return;
    }

    // do stuff
});
```

Hope this helps someone!

Comment: This code is just for manifest version 2, now it does not work for manifest version 3